# Which Chrome shortcuts can't be overwritten?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/commands/) for the `commands` api for Chrome Extensions says:

> Certain Chrome shortcuts (e.g. window management) always take priority over Extension Command shortcuts and can not be overwritten.

But I can't seem, to find a reference for which shortcuts specifically cannot be overwritten.

Comment: In the past those were Ctrl- and Ctrl-Shift- with N, T, W. Now they can be overridden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from [command_service.cc](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:chrome/browser/extensions/api/commands/command_service.cc): `OnExtensionWillBeInstalled` calls `UpdateKeybindings`, which calls `AssignKeybindings`, which iterates over commands returned by:

- `GetNamedCommands`
- `GetBrowserActionCommand`
- `GetPageActionCommand`
- `GetActionCommand`

For each command, `AddKeybindingPref` is called with certain parameters, but only if `CanAutoAssign` returns `true`:

- It returns `false` if the user had already modified the key binding.
- It returns `true` if it is a media key:

  - If <kbd>⏯️</kbd>/<kbd>⏹️</kbd>/<kbd>⏮️</kbd>/<kbd>⏭️</kbd> without any modifier.
- If the command is *global* (works when Chrome window is not active), it returns `true` if it is a named command, and either the extension has `kCommandsAccessibility` permission, or the key is (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>)+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+(<kbd>0</kbd>...<kbd>9</kbd>)
- If it is not a global command, then it returns the result of `IsChromeAccelerator`.

`IsChromeAccelerator` has two definitions:

- For [`cocoa`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:chrome/browser/ui/cocoa/accelerator_utils_cocoa.mm;l=18), [`keyEventWithType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1533943-keyeventwithtype) is queried for a matching key event.
- For [`aura`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:chrome/browser/ui/views/accelerator_utils_aura.cc;l=18), list returned from `GetAcceleratorList` is checked for a match, which is populated from:

  - `kAcceleratorMap`,
  - and if `kUIDebugTools` feature is enabled: `kUIDebugAcceleratorMap`

Here is the list from [`kAcceleratorMap`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:chrome/browser/ui/views/accelerator_table.cc;l=29):

- <kbd>F7</kbd> (if not ChromeOS-Ash)
- <kbd>F12</kbd>
- <kbd>ESC</kbd>

If not macOS:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>
- (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>)+(<kbd>0</kbd>...<kbd>9</kbd>)
- (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>)+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
- (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>)+<kbd>+</kbd>
- (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>)+<kbd>-</kbd>
- (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>)+<kbd>0</kbd>
- <kbd>F1</kbd>
- <kbd>F3</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>
- <kbd>F5</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>
- <kbd>F6</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>
- <kbd>F10</kbd>
- <kbd>F11</kbd>
- (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>)+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
- (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>)+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
- (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>)+<kbd>T</kbd>
- (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>)+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>)+<kbd>N</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

If Linux or ChromeOS-Lacros:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+(<kbd>0</kbd>...<kbd>9</kbd>)
- <kbd>Browser: Favorites</kbd>

If Linux or ChromeOS:

- <kbd>Browser: Back</kbd>
- <kbd>Browser: Forward</kbd>
- <kbd>Browser: Home</kbd>
- <kbd>Browser: Refresh</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Browser: Refresh</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Browser: Refresh</kbd>

If ChromeOS-Ash:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Browser: Back</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>OEM: 2</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>OEM: 2</kbd>
- <kbd>Browser: Favorites</kbd>
- <kbd>Browser: Stop</kbd>
- <kbd>Launcher/Search</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>

If not macOS or ChromeOS-Ash:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>
- <kbd>Menu</kbd>
- <kbd>Browser: Search</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

Debug keys added from [`kUIDebugAcceleratorMap`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:chrome/browser/ui/views/accelerator_table.cc;l=249):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this and write all that out. This is exactly what I wanted to understand.